# SVG element not being responsive - when screen resized

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a map-container which shows world map, that is supposed to be responsive  but it does not work when I run it and resize the page, I cant find whats the issue. what it is expected when screen is resized. here's my code

```js
    var tooltipMap = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")  
        .attr("class", "map-tooltip shadow")            
        .style("opacity", 0);                

      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([0, 62 ])
        .scale(150)
        .rotate([0, 0]);

      var svg = d3.select("#map-container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr('viewBox', "0 0 "+(width)+" "+(height))
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMid')
        .attr("class","chart");
      
      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

      var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

      defs.append("svg:pattern")
        .attr("id", "bgImg")
        .attr("width", 6)
        .attr("height", 6)
        .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", '../assets/img/map-tile.png')
        .attr("width", 6)
        .attr("height", 6)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0);
      
      var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("width", width+160)
        .attr("height", height);

      // load and display the World
      d3.json("om.json", function (error, topology) {
        g.selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("fill", "url(#bgImg)")
          .attr("d", path);
      });
```

```css
<script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<div id="map-container"></div>
```

Basically as of what appears,

.attr("class","chart");

does not work, wondering why ?

Solution -

CSS - strange as hell, but this was the issue my css was not placed perfectly. !!! Facepalm !!!

.chart{ width:100%;    height:100%; }

Comment: You're setting all the SVG elements sizes based on pixel sizes, which might make the entire SVG responsive but the elements inside that SVG element have actually been sized based on pixel sizes, which would make them sized based on your screens pixel density.

Comment: but it does not show up even if you tell that only svg becomes responsive, I dont see no difference.

Comment: If the SVG is responsive but not its elements you get a container for the SVG code that resizes nicely, but you may have elements/code inside that SVG container that does not respond in the same manner to the window resizing. My suggestion is completely recalculating everything whenever the window resizes.

Comment: can you explain with code, what you are suggesting ? I am new to d3 and svg stuff @SimonHyll

Comment: Curse me and my helpful nature, I was gonna go to sleep... 1 moment (fiddles with some code), here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/g4s5vto6/ try setting the width and height of the SVG element. Notice how the actual shape doesn't change in size, even if the SVG element is resized? That's because while the SVG container resizes based on the surrounding elements the actual code inside it does not. So if you don't add an onWindowResize event listener and use that to recalculate the size of the elements inside the SVG, they're gonna remain the same size forever, regardless of the size of the SVG.

Comment: @SimonHyll - Thanks for help, got your point completely but I am yet to find my solution....and about curse - that's a blessing though.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Thanks